# El-get installation fails

Tags: emacs

I followed the instructions on el-get github page to install el-get.

I pasted the following code in my scratch buffer.

```
(url-retrieve
 "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el"
 (lambda (s)
   (goto-char (point-max))
   (eval-print-last-sexp)))
```

And I see the following error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable read:errno=0)
  eval(read:errno=0)
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp()
  (lambda (s) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp))(nil)
  apply((lambda (s) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp)) nil)
  url-http-activate-callback()
  url-http-end-of-document-sentinel(#<process raw.github.com> "finished\n")
```

Any tips on how to debug/fix this.

Comment: It looks like the download from github.com failed; it may work if you evaluate the URL-RETRIEVE form again, or failing that, you can always download el-get-install.el manually, open it in Emacs, and `M-x eval-buffer`.

Comment: While my comment is not an `elisp` solution, you could always just download the repository in the form of a zip and then unzip it to your preferred location and then set-up your init config accordingly.  You can also byte-compile everything in a directory in one fell-swoop.  Here is the zip link to the `master`:  https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/archive/master.zip  And, here is the link to the repository that can be viewed with a web browser:  https://github.com/dimitri/el-get   There are options on the webpage to select a branch instead of the master if you prefer.